# SSRS: Is it possible change border color based on series color in tree chart?

Tags: colors, ssrs-2016, reporting-services-2016, treechart

We work with SSRS 2016.
I'm wondering is there a possibility to change a tree chart series border color according to color of series? E.g. if chart series color = "Red" then border color = "Blue".

Yes, we can operate colors based on series values using switch function if the values set is limited, like:

`=switch(Fields!country.Value = "Europe","#black" ,
         Fields!country.Value = "Asia",     "#blue",
         ........, etc.
)`

But if values are too many switch is not a solution.

Can you please advice whether it possible to implement expected conditional coloring?

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes, but not the way you want to do it. Lets say your series color expression is the following:

```
=IIF(Fields!SeriesName.Value = "SeriesA", "Red", "Green")
```

For the border color you can not check for the color, but you can use the same expression again. Like this:

```
=IIF(Fields!SeriesName.Value = "SeriesA", "Blue", "Black")
```

This way your `SeriesA` color is Red and the border is Blue.

Comment: actually that was my concern - I have too many values and can't use switch/iif for this;
concluding that answer on my question is rather no that yes

Comment: Hmm if `Switch()` doesnt work you can always use a custom function.